# Using Ajax and returning json array in laravel 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, laravel-5

[image]I am new to "AJAX" and I have been trying to send a request "ONSELECT" using "AJAX" and receive a "JSON" response in "laravel 5".

Here is my View

```
<select>
<option data-id="a" value="a">a</option>
<option data-id="b" value="b">b</option>
<option data-id="c" value="c">c</option>
</select>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('select').change(function(){
var data = $(this).children('option:selected').data('id');

$.ajax({
    type    :"POST",
    url     :"http://localhost/laravel/public/form-data",
    dataType:"html",
    data    :{ data1:data },

    success :function(response)
    alert("thank u");
    }),
});
</script>
```

Here is my Controller to receive ajax request

```
public function formdata(){
    $data = Input::get('data1');

    //somecodes

    return Response::json(array(
                    'success' => true,
                    'data'   => $data
                )); 
}
```

Here is my Route

```
 Route::post('form-data',array('as'=>'form-data','uses'=>'FormController@formdata'));
```

I also have tried to change the URL of ajax with just only `form-data` and `{{Url::route('form-data')}}`.

Comment: Hello Prasad , What error you are getting ?

Comment: There are no errors but the code just dosen't work

Comment: also in laravel 5 the syntax are suppose to  change thats the main reason

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Laravel 5 uses csrf token validation for security reasons....try this...

1. In routes.php

   ```
   route post('form-data', 'FormController@postform');
   ```
2. In master layout file

   ```
   <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
   ```
3. ```
   var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
   ```

   ```
   $.ajax({
       url: '/form-data/',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN},
       dataType: 'JSON',
       success: function (data) {
           console.log(data);
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 6):

Add error callback to your ajax request to find if an error is thrown,

```
$.ajax({
  type    :"POST",
  url     :"http://localhost/laravel/public/form-data",
  dataType:"json",
  data    :{ data1:data },
  success :function(response) {
    alert("thank u");
  },
  error: function(e) {
    console.log(e.responseText);
  }
});
```

its better to use console.log() to see detailed information even if the response is a json string. Try the code and let us know if something is logged to the browser console

Comment: still no use but it is also about laravel 5 where some syntax are also changing and was released almost 10 days ago

Comment: what response do you get from the controller?

Comment: I am trying to get a json response but in this  function no response is returned at execution. I just want the success response but in json

Comment: Thank you. I was struggling with this part: error: function(e) {
    console.log(e.responseText);
  }

Answer (score 3):

Your jQuery code has syntax error in `success` callback, that's why its not making any `post` request to Laravel, please try below javascript it will work

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option data-id="a" value="a">a</option>
<option data-id="b" value="b">b</option>
<option data-id="c" value="c">c</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
    $('select').on('change', function (e) {
   var data = $(this).children('option:selected').data('id');
 $.ajax({
  type    :"POST",
     dataType:"json",
  url     :"http://localhost/laravel/public/form-data",
  data    :{ data1:data },
  success :function(response) {
    alert("thank u");
  }
 });
});
})
</script>
```

In Laravel , you can just return `array` or `object` and it will automatically convert it to `json` response

```
return ['success' => true, 'data' => $data];
```

Comment: try running `php artisan route:list` and make sure `http://localhost/laravel/public/form-data` route is registered, use above code it will work

Answer (score 2):

You made error in code ,please write it properly.

```
$.ajax({
    type    :"POST",
    url     :"http://localhost/laravel/public/form-data",
    dataType:"json",
    data    :{ data1:data },
    success :function(response){
    alert("thank u");
    }
});
```

**Update**

I just saw your Returning datatype is json , so use

```
 dataType:"json",
```

or

```
 dataType:"jsonp",
```

Comment: if I add an alert  after "var data" it works as alert before ajax but after ajax no response

Comment: open Firebug , and open Net tab in it. And edit the question ,  paste screenshot of giving ajax call .

Answer (score 1):

The problem was type should be "GET" instead of "POST" and

```
route get('form-data', 'FormController@postform');
```

Thank U every one for your help

Comment: Great but changing the method of request just because something isn't working is not a good solution. You may check the console to trace the error for post request if you need to learn. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Better if you are sending all form data then use `data: $(this).serialize()` in ajax, and inside form use `{{ csrf_field() }}`