# Laravel 5.1 data loading

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-5.1, loading

I have to set loading in my view page. I have to display 100 datas which is loaded from database. It is getting some time to display. In that some time I have to show loading animation.

I'm using Laravel 5.1. There I'm using Eloquent Relationships to communicate with database.

Still I did not get any information related to my requirement. I'm new to Laravel.

For example, if I search some values in view page, my request will move on to the `route->controller->model->(retrieve date)->sent` response to the view(same view). In mean time, I need to show loading to user.

Comment: Seeing as you're displaying the data on load, do you really need javascript to do this? Can you elaborate exactly what you're trying to do as I don't really understand. With Laravel, you essentially do all processing in the controller and pass the data to the view.

Comment: Actually if I search some value in view page, my request will move on to the route->controller->model->(retrieve date)->sent response to the view(same view). In mean time, I need to show loading to user. @matt

Comment: Ahh, OK. So essentially you need to create an ajax request to a URL e.g. `/ajax/searchstuff` through jquery with `$.getJSON`, make a route to your controller for `searchstuff()` and do the processing there for the data and return a json request from the controller using `Response::json` e.g. `return Response::json(array('name' => 'Steve', 'state' => 'CA'));`. After that just process the json data in the `$.getJSON` request and you're done.

Comment: ya thanks @matt. It really helps a lot. But Can you share any document or sample code for loading with ajax in laravel_5.1?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599638/using-ajax-and-returning-json-array-in-laravel-5

Comment: I got an ans. thanks a lot @matt.