# Laravel Json Stringify responseText How to process it?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, laravel

My Laravel code is given below

```
public function validateRegisterToBidForm(Request $request){

    $validationArray = $this->getValidationArray();

    $this->validate($request, $validationArray);
    return response()->json();

}//validateRegisterToBidForm
```

Output of above is received in Ajax
If Error then I stringify the output Above and get following json

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"fname\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"],\"lname\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"],\"email\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect\"],\"password\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"],\"adr1\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"],\"city\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"],\"state\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"],\"phone\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"],\"primary_phone\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"],\"pass_dri_license\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"],\"card_type\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"],\"cardno\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect\"],\"cvv\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"],\"fname_b\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"],\"lname_b\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"],\"email_b\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"],\"adr1_b\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"],\"city_b\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"],\"state_b\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"],\"phone_b\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"],\"primary_phone_b\":[\"This field is missing or incorrect.\"]}","status":422,"statusText":"Unprocessable Entity"}
```

How to extract values? What is the correct method?

Comment: take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29789330/6556397). This may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can have this kind of call:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "the/url",
        data: {the: data},
        success: function (myresponse) {
            console.log(myresponse);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

Practically, this is what I use: i.e `JSON.parse();` so you can pick each fields with `err` variable e.g `err.fname`

I hope this helps :)